# How to interpolate values on geography in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to interpolate values on the geography and produce a contour map to show the interpolated values.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

See this excellent tutorial:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Also you might have better luck asking questions about how to use GIS at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your time and providing info! @mkirk